# How to integrate QR Code Reader in iphone apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new in iphone development and we have to integrate the QR code reader in my apps, i have no idea about that some one please guide me how can i start. Give me some sample code or any tutorials links for that. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great library to do such project. Take a look at [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/). There is an obj-c version.

Answer (score 1):

try out zbarSDK! it worked well for me, http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) is the zxing (zebra crossing) google library. It can get you started. Hope that helps!